# Decoupling Capacitor - Multiple Vss pins

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

I'm about to start using a chip that has one positive and two ground connections - I've only used chips with one positive and one ground before.

How should I attach the decoupling capacitor(s?) to this?

[image]

Should I just have one capacitor across pin 20 and 19?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using something inferior to a PCB like a breadboard then the decoupler(s) should go across pins 19 and 20 with pin 8 connected to pin 19 using a short wire.

If using a single sided PCB then ditto what I said about the breadboard.

Anything with two layers or more use a ground plane and have the cap(s) close to pin 20 with its earth-end via'd thru to the ground plane.

Answer (score 0):

If your layout is done correctly, you have a Vss plane under the PIC, so a decoupling cap across the Vdd and Vss pins (19 & 20) is what you need.  Depending on the value of the decoupling cap you might want some additional capacitance there too, like a 0.1uF and a .01uF.  Of course read the datasheet to see if they have any specific decoupling recommendations and if so follow those.  As Andy said if you have a single sided or no PCB you need a low inductance connection (fat trace or big wire) between the two Vss pins.

Comment: My cap has two pins...? I think I didn't make it very clear, I meant that the chip has two grounds.

Comment: Oh, OK, I read it as one of the chip caps with 3 terminals.  Will edit to fix.